# Add custom info to product list magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, product, custom

I want to achieve something (probably) simple.

What I need is to add a simple short text (25 characters max) between reviews count and product price. The text is different for every product. I've attached a picture so you can see where exactly I need this to be.

[image: Screenshot to make clear where I need the short text]

Comment: You have create custom product attribute  after this attribute value get on listing page ---> $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo $product->getData('attribute_code');
echo $product->getAttributeText('attribute_code'); //

Comment: add code what you have tried so far.

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far. Don't want to mess things up. It's a production webshop generating 5-10 sales every 10 minutes.

Comment: @txm, You want to add label as sale right?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara No I just need to include above the price some short info per each product. I have it done in short description but it seems that visitors don't really read that, so I want to have it visible between reviews count and price.